# Zero Section on $\mathbb{P}^1$ Bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fibration

Suppose

\begin{eqnarray}
p: \mathbb{P}(V)\rightarrow S,
\end{eqnarray}

be a projective $\mathbb{CP}^1$ bundle. Is there any example, or is it possible at all, that the morphism $p$ doesn't have a zero section?!

More precisely, is it possible to have a morphism

\begin{eqnarray}
i: T\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}(V),
\end{eqnarray}
such that 
\begin{eqnarray}
p\circ i\dashrightarrow id,
\end{eqnarray}
i.e. $T$ is birational to S, rather being isomorphic.(In other words, $p$ has a rational section, instead of a holomorphic zero section.)

**Edit/Comment** I'm looking for an example such that $\mathbb{P}(V)$ only has rational sections and no holomorphic zero section. My expectation is that it is impossible, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(V)$ must have a zero section.

The reason I'm asking this is that I have a Brauer-Severi variety that seems to have **only** a rational section but by the Lemma 1.3 here, 
https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2374256.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ab68c0e3788da4b940924e71558f974b6

this Brauer-Severi variety must be isomorphic to a projective bundle. So I'm confused, how on one side I have no holomorphic zero section,  and the other side do have a holomorphic zero section...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "more precisely". If $V$ is a trivial bundle of rank $n$  on $\mathbb C^n$ then the blow up of $\mathbb C^n$ at the origin is contained in $\mathbb P(V)$. So you can have both a $T$ as you require and a section.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post, to make my question a little more clear...

Comment: Take $S=\mathbb{P}^2$ and $V$, the tangent bundle. Then $p:\mathbb{P}(V)\to S$ has rational sections, but no regular section. (The word zero section is not a good term for projective bundles.)

Comment: @Mohan So the divisor corresponding to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V)}(1)$ is not a regular section in this case?

Comment: More generally, if $\operatorname{rk}  (V)=2$, $\mathbb{P}(V)\rightarrow S$ has a section if and only if $V$ is an extension of a line bundle by another one. As soon as $\dim(S)\geq 2$, this imposes strong restrictions on the Chern classes of $V$.

Comment: @abx I see, actually in the example I have (also the one mentioned by Mohan), $0\rightarrow \mathcal{O} \rightarrow V \rightarrow \mathcal{L}\otimes I_z \rightarrow 0$, where $z$ is a codimension 2 subvariety.

Comment: @abx But I still don't know why $\mathbb{P}(V)\rightarrow S$ doesn't have a section. Could you send a reference?

Comment: Hartshorne, ch. II, Proposition 7.12.